# How to create a template literal type based on the keys of an interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have these two interfaces that represent some data structures in my application.

```
interface Foo {
  a: number,
  b: number,
  c: number,
}

interface Bar {
  g: number,
  h: number,
  j: number,
}
```

To be able to identify these interfaces by their string names (i.e. when parsing from a file or taking user input), I have the following interface for lookups:

```
interface TypeMap {
  foo: Foo,
  bar: Bar,
}
```

This allows me to create utility types like:

```
type Lookup<K extends keyof TypeMap> = TypeMap[K];
type FooType = Lookup<'foo'>; // Foo
type FooPropNames = keyof Lookup<'foo'>; // 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

The problem starts here. **I would like to create a type for strings like** `"foo_a"` **or** `"bar_j"` - consisting of a lowercase name of one of the types and one of its prop names.

```
type TypePropString<K extends keyof TypeMap> = `${K}_${keyof Lookup<K>}`;
```

Unfortunately, this does not work because an interface may possibly have props indexed with `symbol`s, and those apparently cannot appear in template strings.

Is there any other way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to [Exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) `symbol` from `keyof Lookup<k>`. Works for me with **4.3.5** Typescript compiler

```
type TypePropString<K extends keyof TypeMap> = `${K}_${Exclude<keyof Lookup<K>, symbol>}`;
```

Which gives me ability to enumerate subtypes

[image: Image with a code]

Obviously you won't be able to use symbols as keys in your string types, but I'm not sure if this is possible to do at all inside [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html).

Comment: @szydlovski glad I could help, I wasn't sure my solution would fit your problem. Practicing "Utility Types" in TS is a long journey)